# How can I merge columns in UI grid in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, ui-grid

I have two columns in Admin grid. For ex. 1. First Name, 2. Last Name

```
<column name="firstname">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">First Name</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
<column name="lastname">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Last Name</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

**So How can I merge these two columns into one like 1. First Name Last Name**

Answer (score 5):

**You need to renderer field in UI grid.**

Add `<Vendor>\<Module>\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Firstname` class in field like this

```
<column name="firstname" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Firstname">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Now create **`Firstname.php`** at

`<Vendor>\<Module>\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Firstname.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Firstname extends Column
{
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {   
        if(isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items) {
                $firstname = $items['firstname'];
                $lastname = $items['lastname'];

                $items['firstname'] = $firstname." ".$lastname;           
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the constructor here. You aren't doing anything with it apart from re-instantiating parent class properties.

Comment: Hello, I have tried an it is working fine. But somhow i can not filter that coloumn. Please check this screenshot. It shows me an error. https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/24487458?key=37d992bd65e15d4f64a14f16959f659d

Comment: @SunnyRahevar, have found any solutions for sorting, i'm facing same issue.

Comment: Hello @JimitBhavsar, check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354187/filter-not-working-for-custom-column-ui-component-grid-magento-2

Comment: @SunnyRahevar, Thanks.

Comment: @JimitBhavsar, let me know if this code works for you.

Comment: @SunnyRahevar, Above code is working to add column in grid, but sorting not working for that column.